Closedness of a Joint Set
Original Problem
Define the set
\begin{align}
&\mathcal A \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{\,(x, y) \in \mathbb R^n \!\times \mathbb R^m \!\mid \lVert x - f(y)\rVert \leq \delta\\
&\qquad \text{and }\, \exists\mkern2mu t \in [a, b] \text{ s.t. } g(t) = y\,\},
\end{align}
where $f\colon \mathbb R^m \!\to \mathbb R^n$ and $g\colon [a, b] \to \mathbb R^m$ are continuous functions, $a < b$ are real numbers, and $\delta > 0$. Is $\mathcal A$ a closed set?
Generalization
In general, is it true that any set of the form
\begin{equation}
\{\,(x, y) \in \mathbb R^n \!\times \mathbb R^m \!\mid x \in F(y) \,\text{ and }\, y \in \mathcal C\,\}
\end{equation}
is closed? Here, $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathbb R^m$ is closed and $F\colon \mathbb R^m \!\to \mathcal P(\mathbb R^n)$ is a function that maps its argument to a closed set.
Notes

The distance between two pairs of points is defined as if they were concatenated, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{dist}((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \left\lVert\begin{bmatrix} x_1 - x_2 \\ y_1 - y_2\end{bmatrix}\right\rVert.
\end{equation}
This definition is required for the notion of closed sets to make sense.
$\mathcal P(\mathcal S)$, where $\mathcal S$ is a set, denotes the power set of $\mathcal S$.

Thank you in advance.

Related: If a set is open, its "slices" are also open. Converse?
